# Enumeration and getParametnames method of request object

Tags: servlets

I'm sending the data from HTML page to the Servlet and in Servlet I'm using the Enumeration from `request.getParameterNames()`, but I'm not getting the data in the sequence in which it is send by the HTML page. How can I obtain it?

Comment: You should not depend on the sequence. HTTP defines a map (key value pairs) of parameters. BTW: I just saw another question having the same topic, I wonder under which conditions it does make sense to rely on the parameter sequence?

Answer (score 1):

`getParameterNames()` returns the names of the parameters. Not their values. Use `getParameter(String parameterName)` to get the value of a parameter. [The javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/) is your friend.